# denwer не подгружает папку с иконками

Tags: denwer

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

иконки находятся в корневой папке, но при открытии сайта это папка не подгружается

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте перед /icons/....svg написать $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], если вы используете PHP

Comment: меня там php нет, они прописаны через css. Немогу понять почему все подгружается кроме этой папки

Comment: попробуй по файлу CSS сделать поиск left-arrow.svg, на найденной иконке проверь путь, если у тебя иконка лежит в корне, то как минимум нужно убрать папку /icons/ перед иконкой

Comment: я хочу сказать, если я не использую денвер это папка подгружается в браузере, а через денвер нет. новые фотки добавил

Comment: аааа, понял, в месте где подключается у тебя SVG посмотри там должно быть вот так подключение быть файла /icons/left-arrow.svg вместо icons/left-arrow.svg или на оборот (фишка в слеше / который указывается в начале)

Comment: нужно погуглить тебе про:

абсолютный путь и относительный

Comment: и сразу все станет ясно в чем дело! я почти на 100% уверен, что дело в этом, если что напиши обязательно помогло или нет

Comment: вы не поняли самой папки нет, если я даже не правильно прописал пути, они в консоли во вкладке sources должны быть

Comment: Проблема была в самом денвере, удалил и поставил опен сервер